# How to grab data from multiple field pairs

Tags: php, forms

So I have 6 field pairs within a form (skills and skill rating). Which in code is just the following repeated 6 times respectively:

```
<input type="text" name="skill[]" value="" class="field-1-2 float-left" placeholder="Skill"> 
<div class="select-container field-1-2 float-right">
<select name="skill-rating[]">
    <option value="">Skill rating</option>
    <option value="1">1 (Beginner)</option>
    <option value="2">2 (Amateur)</option>
    <option value="3">3 (Intermediate)</option>
    <option value="4">4 (Pro)</option>
    <option value="5">5 (Expert)</option>
</select>
```

Which returns this from $_POST:

```
[skill] => Array
    (
        [0] => CSS3
        [1] => HTML5
        [2] => jQuery
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
    )

[skill-rating] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 4
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 0
    )
```

What I would like to know is how to insert that data into a database whilst ensuring the pairs maintain their relationship (i.e skill[0] matches [skill-rating[0])

DB schema:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| skill_id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| skill        | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| skill_rating | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

PDO function:

```
    public function updateSkills($skill, $skillRating = NULL, $sessionUserID) {

        $insertQuery = $this->db->prepare("
            INSERT INTO " . DB_NAME . ".freelancer_skills
                (skill_id, skill, skill_rating)
            VALUES 
                (:userID, :skill, :skillRating)
        ");

        $insertQuery->bindValue(":skill", $skill);
        $insertQuery->bindValue(":skillRating", $skillRating);
        $insertQuery->bindValue(":userID", $sessionUserID);

        try{
            $insertQuery->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
            $users = new Users($db);
            $debug = new Errors();
            $debug->errorView($users, $e);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: The values should be in the $_REQUEST or $_POST array. Are you not seeing them there?

Comment: are you looking for a way to add it to the db (mysqli, pdo) or are you not familiar with connecting a form with the php `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobals?

Comment: I've updated my original question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you built your form, the selected value of `$_POST['skill-rating'][$key]` will always have the equivalent for `$_POST['skill'][$key]`, thus using your function, I believe the following should work just fine:

```
foreach($_POST['skill'] as $key => $value) {
    updateSkills($_POST['skill'][$key], $_POST['skill-rating'][$key], $sessionUserID);
}
```

Comment: That works almost perfectly. For some reason it inserts a blank skill with a skill rating of 0 before it inserts the actual data to each row? http://i.imgur.com/Qdp10gS.png

Comment: hm... not sure why that would happen... try to do a `print_r($_POST)` just before the `foreach` loop and see if the first member is really empty (for some odd reason)... also, you may want to remove `value=""` from the input (not needed) and set the value to 0 (or -1) for the first option in your drop-down, just to be sure...

Comment: Ah, if I fill in all 6 input fields it works as it should. It is inserting the blank fields. It stops as one as the primary key doesn't allow duplicates (of this case blank).

Comment: Fixed the problem by just validating $value != "". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Make them arrays, then `$_POST['skill'][1]` will match `$_POST['skill-rating'][1]`:

```
<input type="text" name="skill[]">
<select name="skill-rating[]">
```

You can also loop through them with `foreach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Say user filled 3 skills i.e 6 inputs. You'll get the following `array` as the user submits:

```
Array(
[skill-1] => Python
[skill-rating-1] => 2
[skill-2] => PHP
[skill-rating-2] => 3
[skill-3] => Ruby
[skill-rating-3] => 5
)
```

Now use and loop and create a array to make it use in your query.

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $skills = $_POST;
    $skill_count = sizeof($skills)/2;

    $data = array();
    $j = 0;
    foreach($i=1; $i<=$skill_count; $i++)
    {
        $data[$j]['skill'] = $skills['skill'.$i];
        $data[$j]['skill_rating'] = $skills['skill-rating'.$i];
        $j++;
    }

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);
}
```

**Resulting array:**

```
Array(
   [0] => Array(
               [skill] => Python
               [skill-rating] => 2
              )
   [1] => Array(
               [skill] => PHP
               [skill-rating] => 3
              )
   [2] => Array(
               [skill] => Ruby
               [skill-rating] => 5
              )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient, that is, inserting each row one at a time, but using your current setup (with your PDO function), it should work just fine.

```
for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) {

    if (isset($_POST['skill'][$i])) {

        $skill_name = sanitize_user_input($_POST['skill'][$i]);
        $skill_rating = (isset($_POST['skill-rating'][$i]) ? sanitize_user_input($_POST['skill-rating'][$i]) : NULL)

        if (!$YourClass->updateSkills($skill_name, $skill_rating, $sessionUserID))
            echo "Insert failed";
    }
}
```

Note that `sanitize_user_input()` is just my fictional function that represents doing some kind of input sanitation.